# Uncaught syntax error with Moment.js

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, ionic-framework

I'm starting a new Ionic project, and I'm trying to use Moment.js. However it's throwing an error that I'm struggling to figure out. I haven't changed anything in Ionic or Moment, but when I try to load the project it says:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

And then when I look to the code where it's coming from, it's in the moment.js file. I've used this module multiple times before, and it hasn't given me any issue, but this is my first Ionic project. What am I missing?

[image: This is the error it's showing]

[image: This is the line throwing the error]

Comment: Facing same issue with an ember-cli project. Downgraded to 2.0.0 for now to make it work.

Comment: This worked for me also, but it's not exactly a solution in the long run. I looked at the momentjs history, and it looks like the biggest difference in the newest version is ES6 support or something like that. Since I have no idea what that is and it doesn't seem to affect my project, this will work for now.

Answer (score 6):

The moment.js source file (in the src directory) is written in ES6.  When they do their build it gets transpiled to ES5 and the moment.js file at the top level of the directly is the transpiled version.  The minified versions (in the min folder) are also ES5.

I had the same issue because I pointed to the src version instead of the build versions of moment.js.  I'm running successfully at the latest version now.